# Validate If Each Box Element Contains Only One Item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am almost close to what I am trying to accomplish. Right now, the below code sample checks if there's a **li** tag in a box. So far, it works but if any of the boxes has **li** tag in the box, it just blocks the drag and drop feature of other boxes as well. But when the dragged box is returned to its previous state, then the other boxes can be dragged to the boxes again. What I try to do is:

1. It should be able to check individual box with the **li** tag
2. It shouldn't block the feature for other boxes, if any of the boxes has the **li** tag. Rather it should check individual box having **li** tag

I am not sure if I can make it work without declaring new id or class for each **li** tag, rather expecting make it work as it's. Any way, so that I can traverse the **li** tag and make use of the below condition:

```
if ($('ul#sortable2 li').length > 1) { //This condition blocks drag and drop feature of other boxes if match found
    $(this).sortable("cancel");
}
```

**N.B**: No two items can be adjusted in the box at a time for each section of the boxes.

```js
$(function () {
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if ($('ul#sortable2 li').length > 1) { //Checks if a li tag exists
                $(this).sortable("cancel");
            }
        },

    }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

 #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 15px 15px 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}

#sortable1 ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

#sortable2 ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<!--First Part-->
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
</div>

<!--Second Part-->
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have repeated Ids. This is the first issue, because IDs must be unique.  I changed the IDs with a class.

In order to refer the current change your code from:

```
if ($('ul#sortable2 li').length > 1) { //Checks if a li tag exists
```

to:

```
if ($(ui.item).closest('ul').find('li').length > 1) { //Checks if a li tag exists
```

Working snippet:

```js
$(".sortable1, .sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.item).closest('ul').find('li').length > 1) { //Checks if a li tag exists
            $(this).sortable("cancel");
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
.sortable1, .sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.sortable1 li, .sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 15px 15px 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}

.sortable1 ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.sortable2 ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<!--First Part-->
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul  class="sortable1 connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul  class="sortable1 connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul  class="sortable1 connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="sortable1 connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul  class="sortable1 connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div><br />
</div>

<!--Second Part-->
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul  class="sortable2 connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul  class="sortable2 connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul  class="sortable2 connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="sortable2 connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul  class="sortable2 connectedSortable">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just perfect @gaetanoM. This seems to be a working one, let me test it in my end and will inform you - Thanks a lot.